# Access child template helpers/variables from parent in Meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-blaze

Making a user picker controller and am having trouble getting the users out from parent.

Parent template has

```
{{> userPicker}}
```

Child updates reactive vars, stored as `this.someVar = new ReactiveVar(...)`.

How do I get a ref to `this` of `userPicker` from parent template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up passing a dictionary by reference from the parent and had the child put stuff into it.

In parent html

```
{{> userPicker userContext }}
```

In parent js

```
const users = {};
```

And as helper

```
userContext() {
  return users;
}
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate on how the child is putting stuff into userContext ?

Comment: I think you'd be better off asking a new question. I haven't touched Meteor in quite awhile.